# Automatically change the type of the elements in an array

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a class for my project like this using typescript and react.

```
class myImage extends Image {
   oriHeight: number;
}
```

After I uploaded two images I have an array named 'results' which is full of objects with type myImage.

```
[myImage, myImage]
```

When I click it in browser, I could see the data of oriHeight of each element.

Then I try to use results.map() method to traverse all the elements in that array.

```
results.map((result: myImage) => {
   console.log(result);
   var tmp = result.oriHeight;
   console.log(tmp);
})
```

However, the output of result is no longer an object but an img tag (because the type of Image is a HTMLElement) which makes the data of result unreadable. So the output of every tmp is undefined.

I am confused about that. Why the myImage object will become an img tag when I want to traverse it? I hope someone could help me with that. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] because this doesn't explain exactly what is where. Something is changing things and it's not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your data is actually fine. When you console log an html element, the chrome console displays it as an html tag instead of the javascript object.

Update: It's generally a bad practice to add your own properties to DOM elements because they're harder to debug and you risk them being overwritten by future browser properties. Instead, you could create a javascript object that contains both the image and your custom property. Here's an example interface definition:

```
interface MyImage {
    imageEl: HTMLImageElement;
    oriHeight: number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. But I still could not get the data of oriHeight. It was always Undefined.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. To debug, I would start adding logs back to where you set `oriHeight` so that you can see where it's getting unset, or if it ever gets at all. Or, even better, it's not generally a good practice to extend DOM elements this way because they're a pain to debug. Instead, you could a javascript object that contains both the DOM element and your custom prop. I've updated my answer with that suggestion as well.

Comment: Thx! Really appreciate it!